# How to access build definition project classpath in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to access build definition project classpath in [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322331/306488). If somebody uses this `plugin/command`, then `runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, state)` or `runTask(fullClasspath in Runtime, state)` and any other `Keys.classpath` returns only classpath without build definition project dependencies - deps on plugins like this one. So that I can't access my own plugin classpath at the moment somebody runs the command from his project.

Therefore I cannot fork a java process in that plugin and set it classpath corresponding to my plugin dependencies. Imagine the plugin starts a server so it has dependencies on that server declared and to fork the process you need to get the corresponding classpath of the plugin - dependency on that plugin is declared in build definition project.

Comment: The list of URLs can be read from the dependencies' URLClassLoader, and then converted back to the list of local paths. This is more a workaround than a proper solution I think.